# Calc I Show that the function $f(\theta) = \theta + \sin^2(\frac{\theta}{3})-8$ has exactly one zero in the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I showed that the function has at least one zero using the Interval Value Theorem but i'm not sure how to prove that there is only one. I'm supposed to use Mean Value Theorem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $\sin(\frac{\theta}{3})$ is bounded by $-1$ and $1$. Does this help? What have you tried?

Comment: Show the function is increasing by computing the derivative and showing it is positive.

Comment: $f(0)=-8$ and $f(8)>0$

Comment: I have noted that the function is always increasing with the derivative but i have to prove it with MVT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the MVT directly, suppose that there are at least two roots, $a$ and $b$, with $a\lt b$. By the MVT there is a $\xi$ between $a$ and $b$ such that
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(\xi).$$
Since $f(a)=f(b)=0$, we conclude that $f'(\xi)=0$. But it is easy to verify that $f'(\theta)\gt 0$ for all $\theta$.